# Highlight in Moderator Tools wraps

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, design

When you view the list of flagged questions in the moderator tools, questions with multiple flags have a yellow highlight. This highlight wraps to the next line incorrectly.

Example:

[image: highlighting wrapping error]

See how the highlight wraps all the way to `- 1 hour ago` ? It should probably stop on the *Clicking URLs opens default browser* line instead.

Comment: This is outrageous! The extra yellow is hurting my eyes! We *must* fix this immediately!

Comment: This is because they're putting an unordered list (block) inside a span (inline), which doesn't cause very nice results.

Comment: @animuson - I figured it was something like that. It's not a huge error, just a bug I noticed

Comment: @AmericanLuke - It's a bug, I was just reporting it.

Comment: +1 It is a good catch, though not a big deal.  A bug that has to be fixed.